# Arrays not being initialized properly, all records null. c#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I have multiple text files reading into a string array. Depending on what button is pushed by the user, a rich textbox is filled with text from one of the strings in the array.

Here is the code of arrays being set up. Note that there are more if/else statements doing the same thing but with different files, but i didnt want to waste space on here chucking those in too.

```
  namespace ModNote
  {
public class backgroundProgram
{
    public static int moduleNumber;
    public static string[] noteArray;
    public static string[] moduleArray = new string[7];
    const string dataPath = @"Data\";
    const string gamesPath = "CGP1005M.txt";
    const string algorithmsPath = "CMP1124M.txt";
    const string programmingPath = "CMP1127M.txt";
    const string operatingPath = "CMP1005M.txt";
    const string computerPath = "CMP1125M.txt";
    const string webPath = "CMP1129M.txt";
    const string informationPath = "CMP1123M.txt";


    public backgroundProgram()
    {
        #region // Reading to the array
        // Check the month file exists?
        if (File.Exists(dataPath + gamesPath))
        {
            // Read in the month file.
            moduleArray[0] = File.ReadAllText(dataPath + gamesPath);
        }
        else
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the arrays are null when it comes to assign them, so I put a breakpoint in amongst the code above, and the lines never get executed, where am I going wrong?

Note that depending on what button the user clicked at the start of the program, the value of 'backgroundProgram.moduleNumber' will change.

```
 namespace ModNote
 {
public partial class moduleinfoScreen : Form
{
    public moduleinfoScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shown += moduleinfoScreen_Shown;
    }
    public void moduleinfoScreen_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (backgroundProgram.moduleNumber)
        {
            case 1:
                moduleinfoTextbox.Text = backgroundProgram.moduleArray[0];
                break;
            case 2:
                moduleinfoTextbox.Text = backgroundProgram.moduleArray[0];
                break;
            case 3:
                moduleinfoTextbox.Text = backgroundProgram.moduleArray[0];
                break;
            case 4:
                moduleinfoTextbox.Text = backgroundProgram.moduleArray[0];
                break;
            case 5:
                moduleinfoTextbox.Text = backgroundProgram.moduleArray[0];
                break;
            case 6:
                moduleinfoTextbox.Text = backgroundProgram.moduleArray[0];
                break;
            case 7:
                moduleinfoTextbox.Text = backgroundProgram.moduleArray[0];
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Nope");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why my array code is not getting executed?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely with this line:

```
                if (File.Exists(dataPath + gamesPath))
```

That is looking for the files at Data\CGP1005M.txt. Because there is no starting slash, it will look for the files in the current path. When running a c# program, the current path will be the bin folder.

For example, if the project you are running is at c:\project, it will be trying to find the files at c:\project\bin\debug\data\CGP1005M.txt.

Accounting for the location of your project, are those paths correct?

Comment: Thankyou, If i have a folder in the solution explorer pane named "Data" with all my GGP****** files in, how would i link to those?

Comment: Ah, ok. Go into properties for each of those files and make sure that the Copy to Output Directory is set to Copy Always or Copy if Newer.

Comment: Wow i closed and opened my file and apparently it cant open anymore and i may have just lost my entire project

Comment: Okay i've recovered it, but there is no advanced tab like usual, just the misc tab in properties